# Windows 7 explorer doesn't use details view in folders with media

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I use details as my default folder view, which works fine except for folders that only contain media files like photos or mp3. In these cases the view changes in order to show thumbnails etc. (which I also disabled).

How can I prevent this view switch and tell the explorer to stick to details view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the fourth post in [this](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-general/50646-windows-explorer-how-force-all-folders-use-all-items-template-rather-than-pictures-videos.html) forum thread. It's for Vista but I believe it works in W 7 too.

> Copy the text between the lines below into notepad & save as a .reg
>   file. Watch out for line wrap -- [HKEY_CURRENT_USER...\Shell] is all
>   one line.
>
> ---
>
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> ```
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local
> Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
> "FolderType"="NotSpecified"
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Merging the .reg file will set the 'All Items' template for any
>   folders that don't currently have a view saved with a different
>   template. You can clear all saved views by deleting the
>
> ```
> "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local
> Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags"
> ```
>
> key BEFORE merging the .reg file. If any folders open with a different
>   template after clearing the 'Bags' key & merging the .reg file, they
>   most likely have a template specified via their desktop.ini file.